# Java: Declaring variables with multiple generic "constraints" on them

Tags: java, generics

I have a bunch of classes in java that all implement an interface called IdObject (specifying a getId() method). Moreover, they also all implement Comparable<> with themselves as type parameter, so they are all comparable to themselves.

What I'd like to do is declare a list of such objects, fill it, then sort it and call getId() on them. So my code looks like this:

```
List<? extends IdObject & Comparable<?>> objectList = null;

if (foo) {
    objectList = new ArrayList<TypeA>();
    ...
} else if (bar) {
    objectList = new ArrayList<TypeB>();
    ...   
}

if (objectList != null) {
    Collections.sort(objectList);
    for (IdObject o : objectList) {
        System.out.println(o.getId());
    }
}
```

Basically my problem lies in the first line -- I want to specify two "constraints" for the type because I need the first one to make sure I can print the ID in the loop and the second one to make sure I can use Collections.sort() on the list.

The first line does not compile.

Is there a way to make this work without specifying a generic type without type parameters and using unchecked operations? I could also not find an example of this on the internet.

Greetings

Answer (score 16):

```
List<? extends IdObject & Comparable<?>>
```

This type of [multiple bounded type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) is only possible in class and method signatures, I'm afraid.

So I guess the closest you can get is to define an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface extends IdObject, Comparable<MyInterface>
```

And declare your list like this:

```
List<? extends MyInterface> objectList = null;
```

Comment: Better to say `ComparableIdObject` than `MyInterface`.

Comment: Do you really expect every class implementing `MyInterface` to be comparable to every other?  If not, try `public interface MyInterface<T> extends IdObject, Comparable<MyInterface<T>>` and `List<? extends MyInterface<?>> objectList`

Comment: @finnw *Do you really ...* No I don't, it's not my class hierarchy. But I agree with your solution

Answer (score 0):

How about creating antoher type ;

```
public CompIdObject extends IdObject implements Comparable {
...
}
```

and use this type for your generics ?

```
List<? extends CompIdObject<?>> objectList = null;
```

Comment: Warning: Your CompIdObject is not declared as generic.

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to do similar things before on fields as well, but it can't be done (perhaps someone could elaborate on whether this is a technical restriction or a design choice, I'm not sure.)

The way forward would be to design an interface that extends the IdObject and Comparable, then use that in your generic list definition.